# How to access a c# variable's value in an .aspx page and use it inside String.Concat method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have this in my code behind:

```
string input = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('=') + 1);
```

This is my .aspx page:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="Some text">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtUrl" Text='<%# String.Concat(@"\Uploads\",Eval("text")) %>' runat="server" onclick="javascript:this.select();"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And I need to do this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="Some text">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtUrl" Text='<%# String.Concat(@"\Uploads\",output,Eval("text")) %>' runat="server" onclick="javascript:this.select();"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

- As you can see, I need to create custom "path" in textbox using string.concat joining **\Uploads\** + value of variable **output** + **Eval("text")**

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by writing a method in your code behind:

```
protected string GetOutput()
{
    string input = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    return input.Substring(input.IndexOf('=') + 1);
}
```

and then consume this method in your WebForm:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="Some text">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtUrl" Text='<%# String.Concat(@"\Uploads\", this.GetOutput(), Eval("text")) %>' runat="server" onclick="javascript:this.select();"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I like this solution better, but I've posted the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it public.

```
public string output = string.Empty; // At the class declaration

output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('=') + 1); // On page load, etc
```

Comment: Thank you, I've used solution from MelanciaUK because it suits my purposes the best, but this works too.